# how to use digi addp library with python

Tags: python, dll, ctypes

I've been trying to use the digi Advanced Device Discovery protocol library with python using ctypes.
the context:
Windows 7 x64
python 2.7.5
dll library

here's my current code:

```
guid = (0xbf6db409,0xc83d,0x44a3,0xa3,0x6d,0x21,0x79,0x7d,0x2f,0x73,0xf9)

class ADDP():
    from ctypes import Structure
    class GUID(Structure):
        from ctypes.wintypes import DWORD,WORD,BYTE
        _fields_ = [("Data1",DWORD),
                    ("Data2",WORD),
                    ("Data3",WORD),
                    ("Data4",BYTE * 8)]
    def __init__(self, guid): 
        from ctypes import windll, c_void_p, c_byte, pointer,c_char,POINTER
        from ctypes.wintypes import HANDLE
        import ctypes
        self.dll = windll.LoadLibrary("D:\\Lib\\addp.dll")
        self.guid = self.GUID()
        self.guid.Data1 = guid[0]
        self.guid.Data2 = guid[1]
        self.guid.Data3 = guid[2]
        self.guid.Data4 = (c_byte * 8)(guid[3],guid[4],guid[5],guid[6],guid[7],guid[8],guid[9],guid[10])
        addpopen = self.dll[1]
        addpopen.argtypes = [POINTER(self.GUID),]
        addpopen.restype = c_void_p
        #print addpopen.restype
        self.handler = addpopen(pointer(self.guid))
        if self.handler == None:
            raise RuntimeError()
            self.opened = False
        else:
            self.opened = True
    def isOpen(self):
        return self.opened

    def Discover(self):
        from ctypes import c_int
        srch = self.dll[6]
        srch.restype = c_int
        print srch(self.handler,10,10)

    def Close(self):
        close = self.dll[3]
        close.restype = None
        self.opened = False
        #print close(self.handler)


conn = ADDP(guid)
#print conn.handler
conn.Discover()
#conn.Close()
print conn.handler
```

i searched a lot for how to handle a handle returned from a c function, but couldn't find much about it, i read the ctypes docs for a while, and then inspected the header file too..

the handle is defined in the header file with

```
typedef void* addp_handle_t;
```

so i assumed i had to set 'restype' to 'c_void_p', the function always returns 'None'
its specified in the header file that it returns 'None' when an error has occurred, else it return the handle to ADDP session.

another thing, this dll does not export functions by name... i had to, more or less, guess what function is what by expected bytes in arguments.

any ideas on this?
i've found a project on google code but apparently it didn't go far...
if you need any other details, just say

Comment: I found a copy of [addp.h](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:tFIyv6hz-00J:ftp://linux.mikroklima.cz/MIDAM-CD/DIGI/include/addp.h), but it declares an `ADDPOpen` function that takes a `u_long` vendor ID constant, such as `ADDP_VENDOR_ID_DIGI`.

Comment: Normally one would import ctypes, load libraries, and define structs/prototypes at the module level. It seems reasonable to me to do it in the body of the class definition instead -- but not in instance methods.

Comment: ADDPOpenbyGuid instead...
should I define prototypes for all function, provided by dll, I'll use?

Comment: Are you sure `ADDPOpenbyGuid` is exported? It's not in the header file I linked to. Have you looked at the exports with Visual Studio `dumpbin /exports addp.dll` or Dependency Walker?

Comment: you may have another version of the dll, on my *.h it says "(To be deprecated) Use ADDPOpenbyGuid instead"
i didn't look at exports, only at header